# Case statement causing error - No column name was specified for column 4 of 'a'

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

This query is designed so that each row will have a unique `NAME` value.

The query works fine except when I introduced the `SELECT CASE` statement to select `ROLENAME`. When this is added, I get the error

> No column name was specified for column 4 of 'a'.

How can this be resolved?

```
 SELECT *
 FROM 
     (SELECT 
          NAME, CREATE_DATE, OTHERNAME,
          CASE 
             WHEN ID = 'test' THEN ROLENAME
          END,
          STATUS,
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY NAME ORDER BY NAME DESC) AS RowNumber
      FROM   
          BUSRULES br1 
      INNER JOIN 
          BUSRULES br2 ON br1.ID_NUM = br2.ID_NUM 
      INNER JOIN 
          BUSRULES br3 ON br1.ID_NUM = br3.ID_NUM 
      INNER JOIN 
          dbo.MDI ON NAME = br3.VALUE_TXT 
      INNER JOIN 
          (PERSON
      LEFT JOIN 
          OP_TYPE ON OP_CASE.ID_NUM = OP_TYPE.ID_NUM) 
            ON OP_ID_NUM = OCO_OP_ID_NUM 
      WHERE  
          br1.KEY_TXT = 'EVENT' 
          AND br1.VALUE_TXT = 'YES' 
          AND br2.ABR_KEY_TXT = 'LIST' 
          AND br2.ABR_VALUE_TXT = 'test'
          AND br3.ABR_KEY_TXT = 'NAME') AS a
WHERE
    a.RowNumber = 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to modify :

```
CASE WHEN ID = 'test'
            THEN ROLENAME
        END
```

into :

```
CASE WHEN ID = 'test'
            THEN ROLENAME
        END AS ROLENAME
```

The reason is because when you use CASE clause, it will have no name, unless you define it

Answer (score 0):

The error message is very specific - you don't have a column alias for the column you're creating with your `CASE` statement.

```
, CASE WHEN ID = 'test'
      THEN ROLENAME
  END AS SomeColumnName  -- Add a column name alias here
```

It's extremely important to learn to actually read the words in error messages. They usually contain some relevant information. It's also important to learn where to find the documentation for the DBMS you're using, as it would have told you what the requirements were for `CASE` and shown examples of using it.